# CMake error while building rpg_svo

Tags: ros, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
CMake Error at /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/share/vikit_common/cmake/vikit_commonConfig.cmake:106 (message):
  Project 'vikit_common' specifies '//include/opencv' as an include dir,
  which is not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in
  '/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/rpg_vikit/vikit_common///include/opencv'.  Ask
  the maintainer 'cforster <forster@ifi.uzh.ch>' to fix it.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
  rpg_vikit/vikit_ros/CMakeLists.txt:17 (FIND_PACKAGE)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

---

The error is pretty discriptive, instead of /usr/include/opencv, I am somehow getting //include/opencv when i do catkin_make. Can anyone guide me to a direction on how to fix this trivial problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198058/cmake-error-while-building-rpg_svo/) by [Robin Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1045/robin-singh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-23**:
Are you running this on a Nvidia Jetson TK1 board with Nvidia's build of OpenCV?

**Comment by [Robin Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1045/robin-singh/) on 2014-11-25**:
great catch. yes i am trying to run svo on TK1 with opencv4tegra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a known bug in NVidia's opencv cmake files on the TK1. I don't remember what the patch was, but you can probably find it on the nvidia forums. I'll try to post it later when I dig it up.

The official response that I got from NVidia when I reported this back in May was:

> It turns out that this is a known bug in OpenCV. An upcoming release will contain a fix. In the meantime, as a workaround you should be able to edit the OpenCVConfig.cmake file and change the line: set(OpenCV_ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL 9) to: set(OpenCV_ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL 0)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0